# How to write LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

[image: FollowingUsers]

[image: StatusUpdates]

Above you can see `FollowingUsers` and `StatusUpdates` tables.

In `FollowingUsers`, I store `Follower`'s `Username` and `Following`'s `Username`.
In `StatusUpdates`, I store `Status updates` of users.

Below you can see original query I wrote to retrieve status updates of user who logged in.

```
var list = new List<StatusUpdate>();
list = (from x in db.StatusUpdates 
        where x.Author == User.Identity.Name 
        orderby x.Timestamp descending 
        select x)
       .Take(count).ToList();
```

How to get status updates from followings of logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, although I don't have your database to test it on.  Note that it won't actually be executed until the call to ToList so everything should still happen in a single database query.  Also, the creation of a new list is not needed as it will be overwritten by your query so I've tidied that up a little.

```
var Users = from f in db.FollowingUsers 
            where f.FollowerId == User.Identity.Name
            select f.FollowingId;

var list = (from x in db.StatusUpdates 
           from y in Users
           where x.Author == y 
           orderby x.Timestamp descending 
           select x)
           .Take(count).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? what didn't work? did you get an error message? did it compile? did you just get the wrong data?

Comment: Also, are you querying an SQL database using LINQ to SQL? or something else?

Comment: No Errors. List returns noting.
Using SQL Server Express

Comment: Can you enumerate Users in the watch window and check you actually have values there? (I'd probably move all user names out into a different table, though, and join the two tables on a user ID from that table not user name.)

Comment: Sorry. It works but returns wrong results. It doesn't show status updates of current logged user.

Comment: OK - so your problem is setting up Windows authentication and impersonation then, i.e. it's User.Identity.Name that's wrong?

Comment: Following User Table Data - http://i.imgur.com/mhU6H.png
Status Updates Table Data - http://i.imgur.com/ILabh.png

Debug - http://i.imgur.com/ILabh.png (logged user = administrator)

I need status updates from following users + my(logged user) status updates.

Comment: It returns only "Test4" status that "chaminga" posted. But query should return "administrator"'s status + "chaminga"'s staus. 6 itmes in count.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help :) I did UNION my old list and yours and get it done ;)

Comment: You could instead change the where clause to `x.Author == y || x.Author == User.Identity.Name` which I suspect would lead to higher performance (and definitely leads to cleaner code)